# C# MongoDB.Driver sortBy element in property that is an array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've got a document structure like this:

```
public class CountryDomain{
  public string Iso2 {get;set;}
  public List<EntityName> Names {get;set;}
}

public class EntityName{
   public string Culture {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

this results in something like this as a Document

```
{
 Iso2: "th",
 Names: [
   {Culture: "nl", Name: "Thailand"},
   {Culture: "en", Name: "Thailand"}
 ]
}
```

Now I want to get a list of countries sorted by the name of the "nl" culture.

Sorting by ISO2 works by doing this:

```
var collection = Context.Database.GetCollection<CountryDomain>(Table);
return collection.Aggregate().SortByDescending(e => e.Iso2).ToList();
```

But how do I sort it by the `Name` value of in that `Names` array where the `Culture` is `nl`.
I tried something like this but that cannot be serialized by the MongoDB Driver.

```
var collection = Context.Database.GetCollection<CountryDomain>(Table);
return collection.Aggregate().SortByDescending(e => e.Names.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Culture == "nl").ToList();
```

Comment: I suspect that you may need to extract the value you want to sort by into its own field first (via the aggregation) and then sort on that new field. Are your result sets relatively small?

Comment: @user20042973 No their are into the ten thousands. This example is for countries, but there is also for cities.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of MongoDB querying directly, I think you will need to take an approach demonstrated in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rQOSfZLcW6J). Basically you'll need to do an `$addFields` in the aggregation first to extract out the value you want to sort on from the array. You can then use that generated field name in the subsequent sort specification and then remove it afterwards if desired.

The reason that I asked about the size of the result set in the comments is because this operation is not going to be able to use indexes to provide the sort. So if the *results* being returned (as opposed to just the number of documents in the collection) is large, then this operation may not be particularly performant and may consume meaningful system resources while doing so. That's not a reason to avoid it entirely, but certainly something to be aware of.